# JQuery AJAX Issue without error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I am adding a list of stores to a web page via a jQuery AJAX request. This little utility is not dynamic, just database driven. I have decided to use jQuery/AJAX to transfer the data because when I try to embed PHP in our current PHP CMS, I get a bunch of conflicting errors.

The problem I am having is that I am getting a jQuery AJAX error when trying to make the request to the PHP script, and I am not sure why.

Here is my AJAX request

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"getStores.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
            results(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data.error);    
        }
    });
});
```

The cryptic console error i am getting is this

```
function (){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this}
```

Here is my PHP code if it will be helpful:

```
//database connection
$return_arr = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM where_to_buy");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{  
    $row_array['store_name'] = $row['store_name'];
    $row_array['store_url'] = $row['store_url'];
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

I think the problem might be because I wrapping my JSON in an array?

EDIT:: JSON output from php script as requested

```
[{"store_name":"Example 1","store_url":"http:\/\/www.example1.com"},{"store_name":"Example 2","store_url":"http:\/\/www.example2.com"}]
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you please also post your `results()` function

Comment: can you able to get alert('hello') in your success handler ?

Comment: Are you sure the error signature isn't this instead: `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`? In which case the first item would be the XHR object and not an error message.

Comment: add header('Content-type: application/json'); before echo json_encode($return_arr);

Comment: Is it actually making the AJAX request and having trouble processing the result, or is it failing before it even sends the AJAX request?

Comment: So i changed the error function to get better results, The error function is now outputting "unexpected_token"..The results function i know works because I have implemented this utility before but instead of just running the ajax request when the document loads it is triggered by a drop down selection that filters the results...

Comment: @TahirYasin I tried to add header('Content-type: application/json'); but this still did not work, I thought that this would be the answer based on some research I did, and was surprised that ti didn't work

Comment: @skevthedev did changing the path resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting that weird error message is that the error callback for the jQuery ajax function takes 3 arguments instead of 1, as described in the docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

The first argument is a jQuery-special XMLHttpRequest object, which has a property called `error` that contains the function you are seeing logged to your console. The actual error that occurred during execution of your ajax call is the passed in to the error callback as the 3rd argument.

To see it, you should do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"getStores.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
            results(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, text, error) {
            console.log(error);    
        }
    });
});
```

That will get you closer to the real problem.

UPDATE:

Please show the output from your php script. It may be that it is not returning valid json. As noted in the php docs ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php ), `[json_encode] only works with UTF-8 encoded data.`

You might also check in to `json_last_error` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php ) to see if the encoding failed for some reason.

UPDATE 3:

It seems like your problem may be the path to the php script.

try it with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/getStores.php", // <-- notice the leading slash!!!
        //dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
            //results(data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, text, error) {
            console.log(error);    
        }
    });
});
```

or, putting it all back together if the above logs the correct json output to the console...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/getStores.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
            results(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, text, error) {
            console.log(error);    
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped alot...The error is now outputting an error of "Unexpected token"

Comment: @skevthedev check out the edits and please provide a little more info about the php side of things.

Comment: thanks! i posted my json output above and I am looking into the links you posted

Comment: thanks for the help again!the problem is I can't even get the success function to trigger...the JSON i get when I run the php script is above in my initial post...I also added header('Content-type: application/json');  to the script, thinking that might have been the problem

Comment: UPDATE: forgot to comment out datatype...when i changed that all i got was the source with various js scripts

Comment: @skevthedev what is the path to the php script? and what is the path to the page with the js on it? It may be that you need to reference the path as `/getStores.php`

Comment: I figured it out with your help...not only did i have to do the "/" but i had to use the absolute path, i originally didnt think i needed to do this because in my other implementation of this tool i only had to use the relative path..Thanks for all your help!